# IsInView and each

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport

Is there a way to set [IsInView](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview) to wait for each element with the same class, so I don't have to call them one by one?

For example if I have three sections, I just want to call them like this:

```
$(".section").on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
  if (isInView) {
    $(this).show();
  }
});
```

So that all three section appear one by one:

```
<div id="section-1" class="section">
</div>
<div id="section-2" class="section">
</div>
<div id="section-3" class="section">
</div>
```

EDIT:
I've also tried with each but that doesn't work either:

```
$('.section').each(function() {
  $(this).on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
    if (isInView) {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use a foreach loop?

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't work.

Comment: I've edited to show each as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays jQuery is considered an overhead.
In pure, vanilla JavaScript the [IntersectionObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) is a good tool for the task:

```js
const inViewport = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    entry.target.classList.toggle("is-inviewport", entry.isIntersecting);
  });
};

document.querySelectorAll('[data-inviewport]').forEach(EL => {
  new IntersectionObserver(inViewport).observe(EL, { /*options*/ });
});
```

```css
.section { /* THIS DEMO ONLY */
  height:100px; background:#0bf; margin: 150vh 0; 
}


/* inViewport */

[data-inviewport="fadein"] { 
  transition: 2s;
  opacity: 0;
}
[data-inviewport="fadein"].is-inviewport {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="section" data-inviewport="fadein">1</div>
<div class="section" data-inviewport="fadein">2</div>
<div class="section" data-inviewport="fadein">3</div>
```

For more observer options read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#Intersection_observer_options

Comment: Wow, thanks for this! I've given up and used a function for each element but I'll find time to call it like this. It so much cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

You could put them in promises and wait until they're all finished with:

```
Promise.all([
      promise1(),
      promise2(),
      promise3()
    ])
.then(showThem)
```

But I think your issue is not with async behaivour, but with the selector, cause I believe JQuery just gets one element when you do $('section'), so doing a forEach loop on that makes no sense. I am not sure how to do it with jquery, but I would do it like this

```
document.getElementsByClassName("section").forEach(sectionElement => {
  sectionElement.on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
    if (isInView) {
      sectionElement.show();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Would you mind posting an example?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. I've added what I think you need.  I am not sure what inView() does. If you just want to render all sections at the same time, I don't think you need that eventlistener and can just immedeately do sectionElement.show in the forEach loop

Comment: Thanks for this, but sadly each and IsInView won't work well. I've edited jQuery each example as well.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on what you want to do with isInView and what the code looks like