I have a problem with a javascript on scroll
I am trying to  make a picture stay on top of the site when its first loaded in the middle of the site change it and in the end of the site make it reapear but to be responsive and not like in the code below that i made but im stuck and i dont know how to link it to a top and bottom section of the site to make it work on any resolution of screen.
Thank you.
$(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) {
      $(".navbar-brand img").attr("src", "img/logo_big2.png");
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 1000) {
      $(".navbar-brand img").attr("src", "img/logo_big.png");
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 4600) {
      $(".navbar-brand img").attr("src", "img/logo_big3.png");
    }
  });
});

I tried putting id-s but since im not that good at that it doesnt work

If I've understood what you're asking, it seems that you need to calculate the values (ie. the 1000 and 4600) based on the scroll height/screen height - is that correct?

Why don't you use else if

You can use jQuery to calculate the positions of these sections dynamically:
Ensure your HTML has identifiable sections:
<body>
  <div id="top-section"></div>
  <div id="middle-section"></div>
  <div id="bottom-section"></div>
</body>

jQuery:
$(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

  // Get the offsets for each section
  var topSectionOffset = $('#top-section').offset().top;
  var middleSectionOffset = $('#middle-section').offset().top;
  var bottomSectionOffset = $('#bottom-section').offset().top;

  if (scrollTop >= topSectionOffset && scrollTop < middleSectionOffset) {
   $(".navbar-brand img").attr("src", "img/logo_big.png");
  } else if (scrollTop >= middleSectionOffset && scrollTop < bottomSectionOffset) {
   $(".navbar-brand img").attr("src", "img/logo_big2.png");
  } else if (scrollTop >= bottomSectionOffset) {
    $(".navbar-brand img").attr("src", "img/logo_big3.png");
  }
  });
});


if (scrollTop >= topSectionOffset && scrollTop <= middleSectionOffset) { (i added an equal to the code and now it works perfectly and its responsive thank you very much :3)

Querying the DOM in a scroll event is a really big no-no. Cache the jQuery object Elements beforehand

Instead of $(window).scroll(function () { use the preferred $(window).on("scroll", function () {

Also, this seems achievable using the preferred methods for the job, and that's the IntersectionObserver API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74812284/383904
